# Error: mod version information must be incremented prior to updating tModLoader

Tags: computer-science

I created a mod for tModLoader and got this error.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEdF3.png).
If necessary I can provide the code from the steam log

I tried changing the version and even recoding somehow, but still the same error (this happened even with other mods)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.